# mod_mono install in apache ubuntu 10.10

Tags: apache-2.2, mono

I have installed mod_mono and apache as per the instructions mentioned

in

http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx

when i run i also get the error message mentioned towards last.

but when i hit

http://localhost/test/index.aspx

i get following error

Server Error in '/' Application
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Resource URL: /test/
Version information: Mono Version: 2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433

what is the problem ? i am so near yet so far !

Comment: This is not the right forum for the question. Either try serverfault or post to mono-list (http://www.mono-project.com/Mailing_Lists)

Comment: Just to commiserate, I'm experiencing a very similar problem myself, though on a brand new RHEL machine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've tried this already, but it's worth mentioning:

Mono will return a 404 if you request a file it doesn't have permission to access. When I was having the same problem, I tried absolutely everything else I could imagine, including some 20 different conf files and about four hours a-Googling. In the end, a simple `cd` to the app directory followed by `chmod -R 755` did the trick.